# set of integer modulo m for composite values

Tags: finite-fields

Is there a Set of integer modulo m, Zm, where m is composite and the set is a field, (all of its elements having a multiplicative inverse) ?

I have heard that the set of integer modulo 4 cannot be a field. Why is that?

Comment: if $ab=n$ with $0<a,b<n$, then suppose $ac\equiv 1$. What happens when we multiply both sides by $b$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\ m = ab\ $ is composite then mod $\,ab\!:\ ab\equiv 0\,$ but $\,a,b\not\equiv 0.\,$ If $\,a^{-1}\,$ existed then multiplying through by it we obtain that $\,0\equiv a^{-1}(ab) \equiv (a^{-1}a)b \equiv b,\,$ contradiction.

**Alternatively**, $ $ recall, by Bezout, that: $\ a\,$ is invertible mod $\,m\iff a\,$ is coprime to $\,m.\,$ Hence, if $\,m\,$ is composite then there exist noninvertibles besides $0,\,$ e.g. any proper divisor of $\,m.$